# Is there a more elegant way to pass a big object variable to jq?

Tags: json, linux, jq

I have the following JSON input to transform (an array of hundreds of similar objects):

```
[{
    "Nmarch\u00e9": "2013-90006",
    "SIRETMandataire": null,
    "LibelleEntiteMandataire": "R\u00e9gion Bretagne",
    "SIRETAcheteur": null,
    "LibelleAcheteur": null,
    "Nature": null,
    "Objet": "PBF Formation qualifiante 2013 Monteur en construction bois lot 4",
    "CodeCPV": null,
    "Type ": "Services",
    "Procedure": "MAPA - art 30 - au dessus des seuils",
    "CodePostalCommuneExecution": 35000.0,
    "NomCommuneExecution": "Rennes",
    "CodeINSEEExecution": null,
    "GranulariteINSEEExecution": null,
    "MillesimeMandatement": 2013,
    "DateNotification": "2013-10-01",
    "Montant mandate TTC": 245526,
    "Montant mandate HT": null,
    "Montant attribue TTC": 245526,
    "Montant attribue HT": null,
    "Date de cloture": null,
    "Duree": null,
    "SIRETContractant": 300599123,
    "DenominationSociale": "AFPA DIRECTION REGIONALE BRETAGNE",
    "Role": "Titulaire",
    "CodePostal": 35208,
    "Dpt ID ": 35,
    "D\u00e9partement": "Ille-et-Vilaine",
    "Commune": "RENNES",
    "Taille": "10 000 et plus",
    "Taille des entreprises par categorie officielle": "Grande entreprise",
    "Code NAF": 8559,
    "Libelle NAF": "ENSEIGNEMENT",
    "Libelle SBA": "Administration publique\/enseignement",
    "Libelle CCI": "Tertiaire non marchand",
    "geolocalisation": null
}
]
```

In `Procedure`, I have a lot of invalid values that I need to replace through a value mapping. I consequently want to feed a JSON object to my jq transform, with the invalid values as keys and the right values as values:

```
 {
    "MAPA - art 28": "Procédure adaptée",
    "MAPA - art 30 - au dessus des seuils": "Procédure adaptée",
    "MAPA - art 30 - en dessous des seuils": "Procédure adaptée",
    "Proc. adaptée/allégée (art.28et30)": "Procédure adaptée",
    "Procédure adaptée (MAPA)": "Procédure adaptée",
    "Appel d'offre ouvert": "Appel d'offres ouvert",
    "appel d'offres ouvert": "Appel d'offres ouvert",
    "Appel d'offre ouvert (art.33)": "Appel d'offres ouvert",
    "Appel d'offre restreint": "Appel d'offres restreint",
    "Achat direct": "Marché négocié sans publicité ni mise en concurrence préalable",
    "Négocié avec pub (art.35I)": "Procédure négociée avec mise en concurrence préalable",
    "Procédure négociée après pub": "Procédure négociée avec mise en concurrence préalable",
    "Procédure négociée après pub.": "Procédure négociée avec mise en concurrence préalable",
    "Procédure négociée sans pub": "Marché négocié sans publicité ni mise en concurrence préalable",
    "Procédure négociée sans pub.": "Marché négocié sans publicité ni mise en concurrence préalable",
    "Marché négocié": "Marché négocié sans publicité ni mise en concurrence préalable",
    "marché négocié": "Marché négocié sans publicité ni mise en concurrence préalable",
    "Marché negocié": "Marché négocié sans publicité ni mise en concurrence préalable"
}
```

I wanted to declare this object in my jq transform file, but I didn't see how to use the `bla as var` syntax to declare a variable with foreign data (ideally I'd like to declare it as a file). I consequently ended up using the `--argjson` command line parameter.

This works (I get JSON output with replaced values), but I wish I could have a cleaner command and make it more maintainable:

```
cat temp.json | jq --argjson procedures '{"MAPA - art 28":"Procédure adaptée","MAPA - art 30 - au dessus des seuils":"Procédure adaptée","MAPA - art 30 - en dessous des seuils":"Procédure adaptée","Proc. adaptée/allégée (art.28et30)":"Procédure adaptée","Procédure adaptée (MAPA)":"Procédure adaptée","Appel d\u0027offre ouvert":"Appel d\u0027offres ouvert","appel d\u0027offres ouvert":"Appel d\u0027offres ouvert","Appel d\u0027offre ouvert (art.33)":"Appel d\u0027offres ouvert","Appel d\u0027offre restreint":"Appel d\u0027offres restreint","Achat direct":"Marché négocié sans publicité ni mise en concurrence préalable","Négocié avec pub (art.35I)":"Procédure négociée avec mise en concurrence préalable","Procédure négociée après pub":"Procédure négociée avec mise en concurrence préalable","Procédure négociée après pub.":"Procédure négociée avec mise en concurrence préalable","Procédure négociée sans pub":"Marché négocié sans publicité ni mise en concurrence préalable","Procédure négociée sans pub.":"Marché négocié sans publicité ni mise en concurrence préalable","Marché négocié":"Marché négocié sans publicité ni mise en concurrence préalable","marché négocié":"Marché négocié sans publicité ni mise en concurrence préalable","Marché negocié":"Marché négocié sans publicité ni mise en concurrence préalable"}' -f jq-filter.jq
```

For your information, here is jq-filter.jq:

```
{
  "$schema": "../../schémas/json/paquet.json",
  "marches" : [.[] | {
      id: ."Nmarché",
      acheteur: {
          id: .SIRETMandataire,
          nom: .LibelleEntiteMandataire
      },
      nature: .Nature,
      objet: .Objet,
      codeCPV: .CodeCPV,
      procedure: $procedures[.Procedure],
      lieuExecution: {
          code: ( .CodeINSEEExecution //.CodePostalCommuneExecution),
          nom: .NomCommuneExecution,
          typeCode: (if .CodeINSEEExecution != null  then "Code commune" elif .CodePostalCommuneExecution != null then "Code postal" else null end)
      },
      dateNotification: .DateNotification,
      montant: ."Montant Attribue HT",
      dureeMois: null,
      titulaires: {
          id: .SIRETContractant,
          denominationSociale: .DenominationSociale
      }
  }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a reason you can't use [--slurpfile or --argfile](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq) ?

> --slurpfile variable-name filename:
>
> This option reads all the JSON texts in the named file and binds an array of the parsed JSON values to the given global variable. If you run jq with --argfile foo bar, then $foo is available in the program and has an array whose elements correspond to the texts in the file named bar.
>
> --argfile variable-name filename:
>
> Do not use. Use --slurpfile instead.
>   (This option is like --slurpfile, but when the file has just one text, then that is used, else an array of texts is used as in --slurpfile.)

Assuming you put your mapping into `procedures.json` and you change your filter a bit as so:

```
  procedure: $procedures[0][.Procedure],
```

then you can use --slurpfile:

```
$ jq --slurpfile procedures procedures.json -f jq-filter.jq temp.json
```

or you use --argfile (although the docs say not to)

```
$ jq --argfile procedures procedures.json -f jq-filter.jq temp.json
```

without any other change to your code.

Comment: Hi! That was quick :) To be honest, I hadn't understood how slurpfile worked, but I guess it's time to put it to the test.

Comment: I just tried it on my machine and it appeared to work as documented.  I'm not really sure why the docs say not to use `--argfile`.  It seems to work too.

Comment: Great, I went for the --slurpfile option. Thanks!

Comment: @jq170727 - The author of the admonition not to use the --argfile switch most likely anticipated that it would eventually be removed, as its semantics are slightly convoluted.  Or maybe he just wanted to reduce the torrent of "bug reports" arising because of the latter.

Comment: I have as js.json: `[{"doc": "sqlite"},{..}]` and with `--slurpfile json js.json` I get `jq: Bad JSON in --slurpfile json [..Could not open [.. No such file or directory`